# AttributeError: 'TaxiEnv' object has no attribute 's'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, openai-gym

I am trying to use TaxiEnvironment of OpenAI Gym. I have written the following lines of code and I am getting the following error.

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import random
env = gym.make("Taxi-v3")
env.render()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\KESABC~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11956/4159949162.py in <module>
      1 env = gym.make("Taxi-v3")
----> 2 env.render()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py in render(self, mode, **kwargs)
    284 
    285     def render(self, mode="human", **kwargs):
--> 286         return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
    287 
    288     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py in render(self, mode, **kwargs)
    284 
    285     def render(self, mode="human", **kwargs):
--> 286         return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
    287 
    288     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\toy_text\taxi.py in render(self, mode)
    220         out = self.desc.copy().tolist()
    221         out = [[c.decode("utf-8") for c in line] for line in out]
--> 222         taxi_row, taxi_col, pass_idx, dest_idx = self.decode(self.s)
    223 
    224         def ul(x):

AttributeError: 'TaxiEnv' object has no attribute 's'
```

What should I do to remove the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. "Can anyone please help me" is not a question we can answer here. If the code you have written comes from the documentation, then you have a tech support question, and the right place to ask is on a bug tracker or support forum - not here. If it doesn't, then you should first read the documentation and make sure you can make *some* simple example work as advertised.

Comment: error shows you full path to code - so you could open it and analyze what can be in `self.s`

Comment: did you try to run it without `juputer`? Maybe it needs real terminal/console.

Comment: code works for me with gym 0.19. I used `grep` to find `.s` in all files and it found it in `toy_text/discrete.py`. But after updating to 0.23 I get the same error. it seems they make some mistake. You mau install older version `pip install --upgrade gym==0.19` or you may wait for newer (maybe without this mistake)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code worked in gym 0.19 but not in 0.23 but real problem is that you use it in wrong way.

You have to set default values at start - `env.reset()` - and it will work.

```
import gym

env = gym.make("Taxi-v3")
env.reset()
env.render()
```